# Definition of derivative evaluate

Tags: calculus

how do i evaluate the question below using definition of derivative? I am stuck at the simplification part

Question: x/(((x^2)+1)^0.5)

i am stuck at ((x+h)/(((x+h)^2)+1)^0.5 - x/((x^2)+1)^0.5)/h

Comment: Why would you want to use the definition of derivative on something like that? There's a reason people invented the chain rule, the quotient rule, and so on.

Comment: yes i understand but now i am trying to solve it using the definition.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

is the function and you want to compute

\begin{align}
f(x-h)-f(x)&=\frac{x+h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\\
&=\frac{(x+h)\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}}
\end{align}

Now apply the third binomial formula to get rid of the difference of roots in the numerator.

---

next step:

$$=\frac{(x+h)^2\bigl(x^2+1\bigr)-x^2\bigl((x+h)^2+1\bigr)}{\left[(x+h)\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}\right]\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{(x+h)^2+1}}$$

now sharply check for terms in the numerator that cancel before expanding and simplifying.

Comment: you didn't divide by h in the initial step

Comment: It was intentional to keep the formulas simple. Thus one should expect a factor of h in the numerator after simplification of the binomial formula. Then divide by h the equation formed by the first and last term in the chain of equations.

Comment: could you provide a little more hint as i'm stil unsure how to simplify using the binomial formula with the numerator or the denominator

Comment: Since there is a difference, you expand the fraction by the sum of the terms. Hint added.